# NSString to NSDate conversion..is there a better way?

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a NSString object of format "Tuesday 14th October" to NSDate, of format "Tuesday, 14 Oct". This is what I tried,

```
NSString *day = @"Tuesday 14th October";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM"];

NSArray *dateComponets = [day componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; 
NSString *dayOfTheWeek = dateComponets[0];
NSString *date = [dateComponets[1] substringToIndex:2];
NSString *month = [dateComponets[2] substringToIndex:3];
NSString *newDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", dayOfTheWeek,date, month];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:newDay];
NSLog(@"date : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

It seems to work but I felt its a bit clunky..do you guys know more elegant/better/standard way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store an NSDate in Core Data - So:

```
NSString *day = @"Tuesday 14th October";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMM"];
myCoreDataObject.savedDate = [dateformatter dateFromString: day];
```

Then do the reverse when you want to display it:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM"];
myLabel.text = [dateformatter stringFromDate: myCoreDataObject.savedDate];
```

- Don't actually allocate a new data formatter each time, its really slow.
- The locale will default to the system one, so you don't need to explicitly set it necessarily

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an "NSDate of firmat X"; you've fundamentally failed to understand `NSDate`. It's a timestamp. It identifies an objective instant in time. It has no format.

Just use `NSDateFormatter` for whatever it is you actually want to do. It can parse a string into a date and vice versa. Don't write your own hacky text parsing. Don't touch `NSDateComponents` at all.

Comment: thx for the comment..I may have got it wrong..hence the question. I have series of timestamps, for example, tomorrow, today, 12th Oct 14, Tuesday 14th October etc..and for each of these timestamps I need to persist a bunch of data in Core Data..now..instead of storing the timestamps as is..I was hoping to store these timestamps consistently so I can do comparisons more easily down the track..did I miss the point here too..I've just started to learn iOS..so happily learn from the pros..